# Javascript - How can I generate a WAV file with beeps?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make some noises with javascript so :

## What i want :

is there a way in javascript to generate a continuous series of beeps in increasing amplitude and export it into a WAV file?

## What i've done:

i checked this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) but it was about working with WebApi and this is not what i want.

Comment: Sure... you'll have to create the file from a **very** low-level though, and deal with raw byte buffers.

Comment: @user1538301 Ok, but can you help me where should i start ?

Comment: @user1538301 I know but you can help me where should i search for it and where could i find a way for dealing with this problem

Comment: You should look at the answer provided. He's provided a link to the specification as well as a probably more feasible alternative if you're willing to get down and dirty with cross-compilation.

Comment: cross-compilation is pain in the ass =) I would generate from scratch =))

Comment: @user1538301 although your sentences doesn't help me at all but thank you.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200994/how-to-play-a-specific-frequency-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Yes, WAVE-files are very simple.

1. Create array of bytes (ByteArray) following this http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ specification
2. Send them as downloadable file.

Comment: alternatively you can cross-compile `sox` into asm.js or WebAssembly =)